# Redirect 404 errors via htaccess sending the user up one level

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

Good day all.

I've recently taken a new site to manage, looking at the webmaster tools on google, I've noticed a big number (around 9000) of 404 errors and looking deeply, I've match a strange pattern:
On some articles I've noticed that some of the images points to a page with a link built like this:

```
www.server.com/year/month/category/subcategory/somecharacter/
```

which actually takes to a 404 page, but, if i remove the last directory `/somecharacter/`, everything is ok.

is it possible to change the htaccess so the user that comes on a 404 page, simply "go up one level" and be redirected to the parent of the page?

so, if at the end none of the pages are shown, the user get redirected to the homepage.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this **generic and recusrive rule** to keep going one level up if current URI causes 404. It will stop when current URI is found.

```
RewriteEngine On

## if current file/directory doesn't exist then
## forward to the parent directory of the current REQUEST_URI
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$0 !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$0 !-d
RewriteRule ^(?:(.+?)/)?[^/]+/?$ /$1 [L,NE,R=302]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/)[^/]+/?$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

if you have other rewrite rules, probably need to have this rule come before them.

Comment: this is for the exact case of my example, but I would like to write a more generic rule, I get the poi of using parentesys and the $1, how can I strip the last /.../ from the url? is it possible?

Comment: @MatteoBononi'peorthyr' try replacing the `([^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/)` with `(.+/)`

Comment: that makes sense, thanks, it doesn't still work as i would expected, but now I've got a base to start thanks!