# htaccess rewrite rules to force a 404 up one directory levek while maintaining the request URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am working on a website that has many directories and subdirectories. Developing locally, I am running php's built in webserver. I really like the way this handles 404s in that if a 404 is found, it serves the parent directory, but maintains the url so that I may parse it and perform some task.

For example:
Given: dir4 does not exist

localhost:8000/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/

This URL will return the index.php found in dir3, however the URL will remain the same, and I can use dir4 to determine some login on the dir3 index file (looking at $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']).

The behavior is also [outlined here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=75061).

When I move my project onto my webserver, this did not work.

I've tried the solution [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27863686/redirect-404-errors-via-htaccess-sending-the-user-up-one-level) but it removed the "dir4" part of the URL.

I am hoping to recreate this functionality via .htaccess. Has anyone successfully done so?

Comment: The behavior sounds more like a bug to me than a feature...

Comment: how does it `maintains the url`

Comment: @arkascha Sure, I understand that, though it is something intentionally provided by the PHP Group in their built-in web server, telling me it's a feature. 

Aside from that, the core question remains.

Comment: I do not see how Apache can be made to do that natively...  You might need to implement some code to do it.  It's like your saying, "if file not found, create a soft link to the same page, one directory up"...  Every redirect solution will replace the url.  You could implement a proxy configuration...?  Proxy from dir4 to dir3?  A bit crazy IMHO.

Comment: I read the page you linked (the outlined here link) and it does say "AFAIK, out-of-the-box Apache does not work this way."